# Unexpected resource type: mipmap expected one of color, drawable

Tags: android-studio

I've added an image asset to use it as src compat for a floating action button, but this the button does not appear and this error shows in the designer, any idea what might be the cause of this problem?

[image]

Comment: When I ran the app the icon actually showed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: you just have to paste the images in the "drawable" folder, so you would have the following address:
`app / res / drawable`